# Shell parameter expansion: $# vs. ${#@}

Tags: bash, shell, parameter-expansion

Within a shell script, as far as I can tell, `$#` and `${#@}` behave identically, both giving the number of positional parameters. Is there any difference between the two, and in what context would one be preferable over the other?

Comment: I do not think positional parameters are an array, so I wonder why ${#@} works to get the count of position parameters.  You cannot use an array-type expansion like `${@[1]}` to extract a positional parameter...  Could anyone explain that apparent inconsistency?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`${#@}` / `${#*}` is the same as `$#` in *most* POSIX-like shells, but not *all* - a notable exception is `dash`, which acts as `sh` on Ubuntu systems.

**`$#` is the POSIX-compliant form, so it is the safe (portable) choice** (from the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html), prefix `$` implied):

> `#` Expands to the decimal number of positional parameters.

---

#### Optional background information

The POSIX shell spec is largely based on the historical Bourne shell, whose only array-*like* construct is the sequence of positional parameters (`$1`, `$2`, ...), with `$#` containing the *count* of positional parameters, `$*` expanding to a space-separated list of the parameter values that is then subject to word-splitting, and `"$@"` - in a double-quoted context - expanding to the positional parameters as originally specified (even if they contain embedded whitespace).

The following discusses `bash`, `ksh`, and `zsh`; `dash`, which acts fundamentally differently, is discussed at the bottom.

**`bash`, `ksh`, and `zsh`**:

POSIX-compatible shells such as `ksh` and  `bash` later generalized this pseudo-array to provide bona fide *array* variables, whose syntax borrowed from the positional-parameter syntax (`zsh` supports this syntax too, but has its own, simpler syntax as well):

`${arr[*]}` and `"${arr[@]}"` function analogously to `$*` and `"$@"`, and both `${#arr[@]}` and `${#arr[*]}` correspond to `$#`.

Perhaps in a nod to the original syntax, these shells (which also includes `zsh`, whose array syntax is simpler, however) also chose to support `${#@}` and `${#*}` *for symmetry*, where you can think of `@` / `*` as the all-elements subscripts of the *implied* array, i.e., the pseudo-array of positional parameters.

As for symmetry regarding element *extraction*:

- Something like `${@[2]}` to mirror `$2` works *only* in `zsh`, not in `bash` and `ksh`.
- The equivalent slicing syntax works in all of them, however: `${@:2:1}`

---

**`dash`**:

`dash`, the default shell (`/bin/sh`) on Ubuntu systems, `dash`, is mostly restricted to POSIX-only features, and does not support arrays at all.

As a consequence, it treats `${#@}` / `${#*}` *differently*: it interprets `@` and `*` as the *scalar* string *list* of the (expanded) parameters and returns that string's length.
In other words: in `dash`, `echo "${#@}` / `echo "${#*}` is the equivalent of: `list="$@"; echo "${#list}"`.

In the absence of support for arrays altogether, `dash` fittingly neither supports `${@[2]}` nor `${@:2:1}`.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth response.